# How to make the best DTO request class?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I need to make a DTO class that represents a JSON request body.

I’d like to make it fully immutable with `final` fields. I’ve already seen implementations based on `@JSONCreator` all args constructor but I also require one more feature.

The DTO class should be flexible and tolerate some missing fields in a request meanwhile ensure that all necessary properties are in-place.

Could you provide me an example of such DTO, please?

Comment: I think you want to research Java bean validation and look into the various kinds of annotations that you can use make such checking happen.

Comment: Yes, but I hoped that widely used recipe already exists

Answer (score 2):

Jackson will automatically handle missing fields and just set those fields to `null`.

It also has some configuration options on whether when serializing responses, null fields should be omitted or set to the special value `null`.

`objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`

On another note, if you are designing an API, you might want to look at Swagger / OpenAPI and define your API declaratively from there (you can specify whether a field is optional or required). Then use the codegen tools to automaticlly generate your DTOs. (They will follow the best patterns and also offer Fluent API style setters).

Answer (score 1):

As @jbx pointed out that Jackson automatically handles missing fields and sets it to `null`.

If you want to ensure that required fields are populated, you need to mark those as `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` or `lombok.NonNull`.

Using this Jackson throws a `NullPointerException` if that field in null while de-serialization of request to DTO class.